# step progress bar for page transition with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have created **a step progress bar with css** and my goal is to use it to make **page transition by using javascript**. I am thinking using **iframe** to hold pages but i have no idea how to control the transition with javascript. Here is the HTML/CSS.

```css
body {

  color: #01ab97;
}

.progress {
  margin: 100px auto;
  
}


ul {
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li .fa {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li .fa::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 5px;
  width: 105px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 63px;
  z-index: -1;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) .fa {
  background-color: #148e14;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) .fa::after {
  background-color: #148e14;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) .fa,
ul li:nth-child(2) .fa {
  background-color: #60aa97;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) .fa::after,
ul li:nth-child(2) .fa::after {
  background-color: #60aa97;
}

ul li:first-child .fa::after {
  width: 55px;
  left: 50px;
}

ul li:first-child .fa::after {
  width: 55px;
  left: 50px;
}

ul li:last-child .fa::after {
  width: 55px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>STEPS PROGRESS BAR</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="progress">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Page 1</p>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Page 2</p>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Page 3</p>
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Page 4</p> 
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Page 5</p>
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any idea

Comment: Personally I prefer just adding a class with JS and letting CSS handle the animation in most cases.

Comment: How would you change page from page with css ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/chris_burns_design/pen/woWWEN May be of some use to you

Comment: Thanks mate this what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

you can use asynchronous approach if you need to fetch data from server and just use javascript to put data into `div`.  If your page is strictly a text I think you could fake the progress bar, if there are assets you could use this

https://andreupifarre.github.io/preload-it/docs/index.html

So for example you could parse your page for searching for assets first, use it for progress bar(with preload-it), when done, put it to container, perform transtion, mission complete